# Docker установить Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

файл docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

все устанавливается, только когда открываю сайт, пишет

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8000
```